# There's "0 but true", but is there "42 but false" in perl?

Tags: perl, exit-code

As per the question. I know there's "0 but true" which is true in a boolean context but false otherwise, but can return something false in a boolean context but with a non-zero value (the obvious place for this is return statuses where 0 is success and anything else is an error).

Comment: Unless you count the empty list `()` or `undef`? Not AFAIK, although empty lists can be gotchas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. (Except for fun with dualvars and overloaded objects)

The truthiness of a Perl scalar depends primarily on the string value. If no string value is present, the numeric field will be used.

False values are: `undef`, `""`, `0`, and to avoid issues by testing the stringification first: `"0"`.

Not everything that is numerically zero evaluates to false: `"0E0"` is true, so is the more self-documenting `"0 but true"`. The latter is special-cased to avoid non-numeric warnings.

However, enter **dualvars**. The numeric and stringy field of a scalar don't have to be in sync. A common dualvar is the `$!` variable that is the errno in numeric context, but a error string containing a reason as a string. So it would be possible to create a dualvar with numeric value `42` and string value `""`, which will evaluate to false.

```
use Scalar::Util qw/dualvar/;

my $x = dualvar 42, "";
say $x;   # empty string
say 0+$x; # force numeric: 42
say $x ? 1 : 0; # 0
```

And then **overloaded objects**. Instances of the following class will stringify nicely, but still evaluate to *false* in a boolean context:

```
package FalseString;
sub new {
  my ($class, $str) = @_;
  bless \$str => $class;
}
use overload
  '""'   => sub { ${shift()} },
  'bool' => sub { 0 };
```

Test:

```
my $s = FalseString->new("foo");
say $s;
say $s ? "true" : "false";
```

Prints

```
foo
false
```

Comment: "under strict"?  strict never gives warnings; warnings gives warnings.